# establish redis connection in python

Tags: python, redis, bayesian

I am using [redisbayes library](https://github.com/jart/redisbayes) in python to implement naive bayes classification. But when I write -

```
rb = redisbayes.RedisBayes(redis=redis.Redis())
rb.train('good', 'sunshine drugs love sex lobster sloth')
```

It gives the following error -

```
ConnectionError: Error 10061 connecting localhost:6379. 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I tried doing it this way -

```
pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
rb = redisbayes.RedisBayes(redis=redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool))
```

But it gives the same error. I am not being able to find a solution to this. How can I establish a connection to redis using python, or this any other way to do naive bayes classification in python using training data from MySQL?

Comment: `r = redis.StrictRedis(host=YOUR_HOST, port=6379, db=YOUR_DB)` has always worked fine to me. You just need to `import redis`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do realise you need to have a Redis server running locally to be able to connect to it, take a look in your process list for `redis-server` if its not there and you don't have a registered service you might need to install it. Take a look at the installation instructions on the [redis homepage](http://redis.io)

Comment: I had installed redis in python using 'easy_install redis'. But how do I make sure that a redis server is running

Comment: Thats not redis.
Thats the client library

Comment: ok..i got it from https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads..
thanks for your answer :)